# What is the meaning of green lines in outline view in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, tables, microsoft-office

I'm using version 0.92.3, sometimes when I've to make a table I use word to make it and copy it to my inkscape drawing, last week I've updated my Office  from 2016 to 2019 and now when I copy tables to my drawing everything seams to be the same, but when I put View>Display Mode>Outline I see green lines that I can't select and erase.

What means these green lines and how can I erase it?

Image:
[image: Table]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Green is usually for clip paths. Check if you can [enable editing](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Clip.html) of those.

Comment: I tried with node tool enabling edit clipping paths but still can't select it.

Comment: I tried using node tool enable editing clipping paths bus still can not edit or select. Maybe I can add SVG file to make easier to understand?

Answer (score 1):

As commented they do seem to be Clip paths: http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Clip.html

The Node tool is showing the green outline only if the clipping path is actually a path and not an SVG object (circle, star). The clipping still works though and can be edited with handles.

What you can always do is select the objects (cells) and do Object > Clip > Release to remove the clipping.

It seems this hasn't been reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape?field.searchtext=clip+path

Comment: I find that if I ungroup it instantly when I pasted it, clipping lines disappear.

Comment: They must have been applied to the group objects then. If you remove the group object, you remove the clipping with it.

Answer (score 0):

Removing green lines.

After importing an image from FOSStriangulator to Inkscape, I show these green lines while at View>Display Mode>Outline. To remove them I just ungrouped the object, as prkos already mentioned.